# Годовой и годичный — одно и то же или нет?

Tags: синонимы

Собственно, вопрос содержится в заголовке. Как Вы думаете, "годовой" и "годичный" — синонимы или слова все-таки отличаются по смыслу?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Годовой и годичный - это не синонимы, а паронимы -  однокоренные слова с разным значением.
 Годовой - получающийся к концу года, в итоге за год; рассчитанный на год» (доход, прибыль, убытки, расходы, собрание, оценка, подшивка; запас чего-л., задание и т.п.).

Годичный - продолжающийся, длящийся в течение года» (курс чего-л., аспирантура, стажировка, командировка, цикл чего-л. и т.д.).

Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200101408)

Answer (score 0):

Годовой - получающийся в конце года, в итоге за год: это могут быть "доход, прибыль, дивиденды, проценты и т.д." Кроме того, годовой - это и рассчитанный на один год - это могут быть "план, задание, программа и т.д."
Годичный - длящийся или продолжающийся в течение года - "отсутствие, пребывание..." Кроме того, годичный - это и бывающий один раз в год, ежегодно. Например, годичные собрания, годичный праздник, годичные кольца на стволе дерева.
Есть ещё пароним "годовалый", который обозначает "в возрасте одного года", чаще употребляется с одушевлёнными существительными.